# Incorrect VM arguments in Tibco6.x Designer

Tags: eclipse, tibco-business-works

I created a tibco 6.3 BW application using tibco designer on Windows.Application is running fine but whenever I try to add Vm arguments (under Arguments tab) in Run Configurations Menu they gets modified after I close the menu. I was trying to add debug arguments

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=9090,suspend=n

for debugging the application but they always gets modified so that some '=' sign changes into space. So whenever I edit vm args and try to run the application I get invalid arguments error. 
I think the problem is similar to this https://superuser.com/questions/392230/incorrect-vm-arguments-in-myeclipse-run-configuration

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know why it was happening, but I found a workaround by supplying vm arguments directly to jre, by going to  preferences --> java --> Installed JREs --> Edit JRE --> Default Vm Arguments.